# VBA Excel Automation (search for hundreds of little WorkBooks (same number of columns) to be queued in a unique Workbook

Tags: vba, excel-automation

I wrote succesully in Visual Foxpro the research of the Workbooks in a specific customer's directory and subdir.
Now I want, starting by the first Workbook, append the the second just below the first and so on...
I wrote, attempting to have success:

```
xStrFName = TRIM(filemm)
oExcel.Workbooks.Open(xStrFName)
oExcel.Workbooks(2).Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy

WITH oExcel.Workbooks(1).Sheets(1)
  loLastCell = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)
  mcomo = .Range(m.loLastCell,m.loLastCell).Row
  mcomo = mcomo+1
  .Cells((m.mcomo,1),(m.como,7)).Paste
ENDWITH
```

I want to select (or directly Paste as above) the row just below the lastcell (m.mcomo+1) and therefore Paste. How may I write the correct Paste instruction (I think it will be simple but I don't know VBA......).Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, see if it works:

```
With oExcel.Workbooks(1).Sheets(1)
 Set loLastCell = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)
 mcomo = loLastCell.Row
 .Cells(mcomo + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
End With
```

Comment: No!   Set loLastCell = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)      says: Command contains unrecognized phrase/keyword.   I defined: #DEFINE xlLastCell  11   and Local loLastCell AS Excel.Range

Comment: What about if you remove the line completely and use 'mcomo = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row'? Depending on your Excel version xlLastCell might be xlCellTypeLastCell (In Excel 2019 xlLastCell works for me), so try changing the argument as well.